# Manipulate struct with pointers queried from Gorm in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, go-gorm

I am practicing by developing a web server written in Go, using Gqlgen and Gorm (postgres dialect).

I started by describing the model of my User:

```golang
# dbm.User{}

type User struct {
    BaseModel      
    Email       string  `gorm:"not null;unique_index:idx_email"`
    UserID      *string // External user ID
    Name        *string
    NickName    *string
    FirstName   *string
    LastName    *string
    Location    *string `gorm:"size:1048"`
    Description *string `gorm:"size:1048"`
}
```

In this case, from what I understand, it is nice to use pointers for certain values in my struct because they can evaluate to `<nil>` when there is no value attached to it. Whereas if I use no pointers, an int will be 0 if no value is attached to it. Alright, this makes sense...if I am not wrong...

However, the difficulty that I face now, is when getting this value out of a Gorm operation on the DB:

```golang
dbRecord := &dbm.User{}

db = db.Where(whereEmail, email).Find(&dbRecord)
fmt.Println("dbRecord:", dbRecord)
// Prints:
// dbRecord: &{{def90b3c-93ff-40f0-8d33-6320dddbe3f2 2019-10-01 14:16:34.365395 +0200 CEST 2019-10-01 14:16:34.365395 +0200 CEST} test@test.com <nil> 0xc0000a1cb0 0xc0000a1cd0 0xc0000a1cc0 <nil> 0xc0000a1cf0 0xc0000a1ce0}
```

This code queries a User where email is "email@email.com", and obviously some fields in the struct point to the actual address of the value. This makes sense, but it is very annoying if I want to read this data. Is there a conventional way of reading this data?

What I tried is to is to convert this struct into a GQL struct (which was autogenerated by GQLgen):

```golang
# gqlm.User{}

type User struct {
    ID          string     `json:"id"`
    Email       string     `json:"email"`
    UserID      *string    `json:"userId"`
    Name        *string    `json:"name"`
    FirstName   *string    `json:"firstName"`
    LastName    *string    `json:"lastName"`
    NickName    *string    `json:"nickName"`
    Description *string    `json:"description"`
    Location    *string    `json:"location"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt   *time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

But again, I get the addresses when I want the values, which makes sense.

So the only way I found is to create a new custom struct customUser, Marshal the data from Gorm, then Unmarshal it into my customUser struct:

```golang
type customUser struct {
    ID          string    `json:"id"`
    Email       string    `json:"email"`
    UserID      string    `json:"userId"`
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    FirstName   string    `json:"firstName"`
    LastName    string    `json:"lastName"`
    NickName    string    `json:"nickName"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    Location    string    `json:"location"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
}

bs, _ := json.Marshal(record)
var s = string(bs)

newRecord := &customUser{}
bs = []byte(s) // This is maybe not necessary

err = json.Unmarshal(bs, newRecord)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Printf("record: %+v\n", newRecord)
// I now get the right format: record: &{ID:def90b3c-93ff-40f0-8d33-6320dddbe3f2 Email:test@test.com UserID: Name:frer FirstName:fwef LastName: NickName:trgt Description:werfergh rthrt hr Location:wfwf CreatedAt:2019-10-01 14:16:34.365395 +0200 CEST UpdatedAt:2019-10-01 14:16:34.365395 +0200 CEST}
```

But this seems so overkilled, and lots of effort if I need to create such struct everytime I need to read data from the DB. Is this the way to go? Or do you know a more convenient way?

Comment: Why don't use use plain fields instead of pointer fields? Is that a requirement? If there's one thing unconventional here then that would be it.

Comment: @mkopriva, you mean `Name string` instead of `Name *string` in my Gorm User struct? I thought that using pointers there is actually conventional, because it avoids confusion when a field is empty and that it returns a value anyway

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Well you would have to clarify what the actual confusion is in that *specific case*, i.e. a user with name `""` and a user with name `nil`, both indicate a user with *no name*, there is no confusion, it's just that one is more difficult to use then the other, right? There are legitimate cases where `""` is semantically not the same as `nil`, however there is less of those cases then cases where those two can be considered the same, in my opinion.

Comment: You say "but it is very annoying if I want to read this [pointer] data". Why? Reading the value from a *string is dead simple like `*Nickname`. What is annyoing here?

Comment: @Volker, by "this data" I meant "this struct", I agree that reading one piece of data is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sql.NullString for string pointer types.

Please see https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Specifically one uses sql null types where it makes sense for there to be a concept of "no valid value for this field".